# Custom combining mobile data and wifi on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have 2 internet sources

1. 3G based Huawei E3533 Dongle (usb) with unlimited bandwidth and speed (Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device )
2. 4G Huawei router (Wi-Fi) with limited bandwith and speed but faster in browsing and better ping (online games and streaming)

I want to use first one with IDM and steam downloads and some specific applications , and the second one with steam games , firefox etc

i have tried speedify but the solution is not good for me it combines the 2 sources in one output using vpn .

there is a hardware solution using load balancer in some routers but i can't afford it . 
any software solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a found a good solution called ForceBindIp , 
simply binds an application to a specific local ip address . 
here is a good reference 
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/